# Swift:Updating UILabel from AppDelegate label doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to update UILabel from appDelegate but the label never change the text. Here is my code:

ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblToUpdate: UILabel?
```

Here is my app delegate:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC") as! myViewController
            if let text = newText{
                myVC.text?.text = text
            }
        }
```

I have no errors of any kind but the the label never updates.

Any of you knows why the label never gets updated?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: why is the label is called `lblToUpdate` in view controller and `text` (myVC.text) in the  the second code?

Comment: Something else to consider. It's a poor design to have your app delegate directly update the text of the label of some view controller. Your app delegate should not know anything about the views of some view controller. Under what condition is this being done? Why not have the view controller respond to some event and have it update itself as it sees fit?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this VC

```
let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC") as! myViewController
```

is not the presented one you have to query the window for it and change it's label as you currently play with another one

Comment: The viewController is presented

Comment: another instance of **myViewController** is presented not the one you instantiate with **instantiateViewController** you need to show your window hierarchy to enable accessing the real shown one

Answer (score 0):

its not working because the label doesn't exists in the time, just pass the value to a variable in your next controller and then in some of the methods for example : 
**viewdidload**  you can update your label with the value of the variable for example :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC") as! myViewController
            if let text = newText{
               myVC.theVariable = text
            }
        }

class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var theVariable = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lblToUpdate.text = theVariable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create new instance because is other viewcontroller, this already exist.

You should access to rootViewcontroller and follow window hierarchy

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   if let vcroot = self.window!.rootViewController {
     if let text = newText{
            vcroot.text?.text = text
      } 
   }
}
```

This code above is example to refer you question.

If you have navigationcontroller is for example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   if let navroot = self.window!.rootViewController as? NavigationController{
     if let childvc = navroot.childviewcontrollers.first {
         if let text = newText{
            childvc.text?.text = text
         }
     }

   }
}
```

If have severals viewcontroller in navigation controller you will access using for loop and check and arrive to the viewcontroller that wish change value property or set values